# Time series analysis of hybrid data with RNN?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, natural-language, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have a time series $x_t\in\mathbb{R}^n$ where $t=1,\dots T$. For some $t$, I have also a message which is a piece of text, i.e. sequence of characters of unspecified length. I assume that the messages provide some information about the time series.

My goal is to obtain a precise model of $x$, taking advantage of both past $x$ values and messages.

How to do it? What is the best model?

I am considering recurrent neural networks in tensorflow. How would you model and train this problem?

My thoughts so far (brute force a little bit): to define a RNN with $n$ inputs, primarily for $x$. I intend to use it for "reading" all the history. That means when a message is received at time $t$, I split it into $n$-tuples of characters and I use them as input to the network. All inputs normalized, last $n$-tuple may be prolonged by blank characters if needed.

Comment: Can you say a little more about the structure (if any) of the messages? E.g. are there a small number of possible, pre-determined messages, a fixed format with minor individual variations, or is each message completely unique? Do they have a constant, or at least known maximum length? Do you need to parse the whole message, or is there a pre-determined way to extract out the relevant, unique pieces?

Comment: The messages contain general comments in English. They may contain some quantitative and qualitative information, some sentiment but there's nothing obviously systematic about them.

Comment: Can you give a toy example of your data?

Comment: What do your targets look like? Is there one at each time step t, or are you trying to process a sequence of x and then get an output? Also about how long are your messages? I have an idea but it may struggle on longer messages.

Comment: The message is typically (97%) shorter than 300 characters. The maximum length is about 1000. The target is to predict next 10 steps of $x$.

Comment: A toy example may be perhaps the following: $n=1$ with $x_t=\alpha_t\cdot x_{t-1}$ where $\alpha_t>0$ changes iff a message is received. The messages come based on a Poisson distribution. A message contains random words (with repetition, ordered randomly): good, bad, blah. If there are more "good" than "bad", $\alpha_t$ grows slightly and vice versa. Note, this is just a toy example, not the actual problem. However, if you give us the way how to solve it, it is likely to be an accepted answer.

Comment: @KarelMacek Why would you directly jump into RNN? Have you already considered something such as ARIMAX?

Comment: ARIMAX can be a good idea. However, how to incorporate the messages?

Comment: There would have to be encoded somehow, there are various ways to achieve that (perhaps the same way as in a RNN). It seems to me that your scenario isn't complex enough to resort to deep learning.

Comment: Any idea regarding the "somehow" without RNN would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea, you could have two RNNs, one that models the sequence of $x$ (RNN A) and another that models the sequence of tokens (words, n-grams) of the message (RNN B).

Then for RNN A, before outputting the next value of $x$ you concatenate its output with the output RNN B and pass them both as features to a fully connected layer.

Here is a crude drawing of what I mean:
[image]
This way the next predicted value of $x$ will take into consideration both previous values of $x$ and the message received at that time. If you don't receive a message at all times I would just have a message with the blank token as input for those times.
I don't know if this has been done before, if it works or how computationally feasible it is, but it sounds like a fun architecture to implement in tensorflow.

Here is some tensorflow pseudo code inspired by this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent) that uses LSTMs (an extension of the RNN):

```
rnn_a = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
rnn_b = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
# Initial state of the LSTM memory.
state_a = tf.zeros([batch_size, lstm.state_size])
state_b = tf.zeros([batch_size, lstm.state_size])
probabilities = []
loss = 0.0
# also here you should initialize the weights and biases of the fully connected layer
for x in time_series:
    for token in message:
        output_b, state_b = rnn_b(token, state_b)
    output_a, state_a = rnn_a(x, state_a)
    #fully connected layer
    predicted_x = tf.concat(output_a, output_b) * weights + biases
    # target_x should be the next x in the time series
    loss += loss_function(predicted_x, target_x)
```

Note that this is just pseudo code and won't work on its own and there are probably better ways of doing it, but you can get the general idea.
I strongly recommend you read through the tutorial I mentioned, and if you've never implemented an RNN or used tensorflow before maybe try something simpler first to get acquainted with the technology.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please add a little bit more information about the way how to implement it in tensorflow?

Comment: I added some tensorflow pseudo code to the answer, I hope it helps!

Comment: This was the idea I had also. Probably your best bet